# How can I see or change default run level?

Tags: init

In the Linux / Unix administration handbook it mentions that you can edit the `/etc/inittab` file to change the run level. I don't have that file on 10.04. I Googled this and found a tip saying that file had been replaced with `/etc/event.d/rc-default` - however I don't have that file on my system either.

Have these been deleted or does 10.04 deal with run levels differently?

Comment: related question -> http://serverfault.com/questions/147430/how-to-change-default-runlevel-of-ubuntu-lucid

Answer (score 29):

Yes, it deals with them differently.

To see the current (and previous) runlevel:

```
runlevel
```

To switch runlevels:

```
sudo init $runlevel
```

For example, to reboot:

```
sudo init 6
```

The init you are reading about was replaced by [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) starting with Edgy Eft 6.10; and, one of the programs provided by upstart is its own implementation of init.
[Here are the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/) for 10.04.

To change the default runlevel, use your favorite text editor on /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf...

```
sudo vim /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf
```

Change this line to whichever runlevel you want...

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

Then, at each boot, upstart will use that runlevel.

Answer (score 3):

To See the Current Run Level Command:

**`$ who -r or $ runlevel`**

If you want chance the runlevel Command

**`$ sudo init 1` ( it will take to u single user mode)**

This are differnt runlevel you can perform :

0 - System halt; no activity, the system can be safely powered down.

1 - Single user; rarely used.

2 - Multiple users, no NFS (network filesystem); also used rarely.

3 - Multiple users, command line (i.e., all-text mode) interface; the standard runlevel for most Linux-based server hardware.

4 - User-definable

5 - Multiple users, GUI (graphical user interface); the standard runlevel for most 
Linux-based desktop systems.

6 - Reboot; used when restarting the system.

Comment: This is an old thread, but no matter.  @Premkumar, yr answer applies more to Unix type specifications such as the  [Lx Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) (LSB) than to _Debian GNU Lx_ or _Ubuntu_ for that matter. Check the run level of yr Ubuntu type distro and you will see that it is probably 2 or perhaps 1, in rare cases where a single user mode runlevel is preferred. See this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) for a detailed description. In Ubuntu, Runlevel 2 is for "Graphical multi-user with networking". The Wiki holds descriptions for many distros.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done by explicitly adding a number to the kernel options in the GRUB entry.

Let's say, you want to change default grub entry from default run level (5) to 3:

```
sudo vim /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Find a place of default boot entry, and have a look at `linux` line. Might look something like this:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=d07e0c99-65ba-4eda-98d8-79693dc79554 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Add `3` at the end of that line:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=d07e0c99-65ba-4eda-98d8-79693dc79554 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 3
```

Try it out:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of the corresponding target of your desired runlevel. You can check which of the available target your system is running as default using:

```
systemctl get-default
```

Supposing the graphical.target is the default, you can further check its definition and detailed information using:`systemctl cat graphical.target`. There are some target units tailored after the corresponding runlevels. You can find which of them are available on your system by listing them: `systemctl list-unit-files -t target`
 Suppose you want to set runlevel 2 as default, you can do this by running:

```
sudo systemctl set-default runlevel2.target
```

You should use this with caution and make sure you are not causing any issues running on the inappropriate target.